# rmarkdown: Tables inclusion in report doesn't work in a loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try to create a pdf report using Rmarkdown, but when I try to make a loop in fuction of the `Periodo` variable,
the tables inclusion in `params <- list(res1 = medias.F)`  doesn't work. I always have as output the report (`test.pdf`) without any result table:

[image: report_output]

My R code is:

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(hnp)
library(multcomp)
library(rmarkdown)


# Open data set 
df_trats <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/data.csv",sep=";")
df_trats $Tratamento <- as.factor(df_trats $Tratamento)
str(df_trats )
names_trat<-unique(df_trats$Tratamento)


# Loop for each Periodo variable

res <- NULL

id.tempo <- unique(unique(df$Periodo))

for(i in 1:length(id.tempo)){
  
  print("Período de tempo analisado")
  print(id.tempo[i]) 
  
  df.subset <- df_trats%>%dplyr::filter(Periodo==id.tempo[i])  
  df.subset$Tratamento <- as.factor(df.subset$Tratamento)
  
  # Models
  model1<-glm(Evento~Tratamento, family="binomial", data=df.subset)
  model2<-glm(Evento~Tratamento, family="quasibinomial", data=df.subset)

  
  B<-hnp::hnp(model1, print.on = TRUE, plot=FALSE)
  qB<-hnp::hnp(model2, print.on = TRUE, plot=FALSE) 
  
  pB<-B$out/B$total
  pqB<-qB$out/qB$total
  
  tvalues<-as.data.frame(rbind(pB=pB,pqB=pqB))
  choose.model <- rownames(tvalues%>%filter(V1==min(V1)))
  
  
  # Anova
  if(pB == choose.model){
    anova.df.B<-anova(model1, test="Chisq")
    print(anova(model1, test="Chisq"))
  } else(pqB == choose.model)
  anova.df.qB<-anova(model2, test="F")
  print(anova(model2, test="F"))
  #
  
  # Pairwise comparisions
  if(pB == choose.model){
    print("Medias dos tratamentos")
    medias <- df.subset %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Tratamento) %>% 
      dplyr::summarize(Mortalidade=mean(Evento)*100, EP = (stats::sd(Evento)/sqrt(n()-1))*100)
    Comparacoes<-summary(glht(model1, linfct=mcp(Tratamento="Tukey")))
    (Comparacoes_up<-summary(Comparacoes, test = univariate()))
    pairwise.res.pB <- cld(Comparacoes_up, level=0.05, Letters= c(LETTERS, letters), decreasing=TRUE)
    medias.lcd<-cld(Comparacoes_up, level=0.05, Letters= c(LETTERS, letters), decreasing=TRUE)
    medias.F <- cbind(medias,as.vector(medias.lcd$mcletters$Letters))
    colnames(medias.F)<-c("Tratamento","Mortalidade","EP","Índice")
    print(medias.F)
  } else(pqB == choose.model)
  print("Medias dos tratamentos")
  medias <- df.subset %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Tratamento) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(Mortalidade=mean(Evento)*100, EP = (stats::sd(Evento)/sqrt(n()-1))*100)
  Comparacoes<-summary(glht(model2, linfct=mcp(Tratamento="Tukey")))
  (Comparacoes_up<-summary(Comparacoes, test = univariate()))
  pairwise.res.pqB <- cld(Comparacoes_up, level=0.05, Letters= c(LETTERS, letters), decreasing=TRUE)
  medias.lcd<-cld(Comparacoes_up, level=0.05, Letters= c(LETTERS, letters), decreasing=TRUE)
  medias.F <- cbind(medias,as.vector(medias.lcd$mcletters$Letters))
  colnames(medias.F)<-c("Tratamento","Mortalidade","EP","Índice")
  print(medias.F)
  params <- list(res1 = medias.F) # ... whatever you have to send to the report
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",
                    params = params,
                    output_file ="test.pdf",
                  envir = new.env())
                    
}
##
# <END> -
```

My test.Rmd is:

````
---
title:  "Relatório dos tratamentos: `r names_trat`" 
author: "Vittia" 
date: "date: `r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  res1: res1
output: pdf_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
````

Please any help with it?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are able to generate the tables interactively, so it's not the code that's a problem. For the likelihood of getting faster answer, if your question is solely about how to handle a list of tables in rmarkdown, then we don't need to mess with all of the "analysis" in your code, simple samples of `mtcars` or similar should suffice. Also, we see no code that actually tries to print `params$res1`, which is likely where the issue will be found/resolved.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the tips!! The mess code is just a cause of the simple sample like 'mtcars' doesn't replicate my error and something in the "analysis" could be the source of the problem.